# Why is the function $\operatorname{Log}(G(t))$ Holder continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, boundary-value-problem

I was reading the theory about the Riemann-Hilbert problem $\Phi^+(t)=G(t)\Phi^-(t)$ where $G(t)$ is a Holder continuous function on a closed curve $c$ with index $\operatorname{Ind}_cG(t)=0$.  To solve this problem one takes logarithms on the above relation and reduces the problem to the additive R-H problem $\operatorname{Log}\Phi^+(t)-\operatorname{Log}\Phi^-(t)=\operatorname{Log}G(t)$ which using the Plemelj formulae has the solution given by the Cauchy Integral 
$$\operatorname{Log}\Phi(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c} \frac{\operatorname{Log}G(t)}{t-z}\, dz.$$
But to use this formula the potential -here $\operatorname{Log}G(t)$- must satisfiy the Holder condition. The books that I have read about this justify this result using the fact that, since $\operatorname{Ind}_cG(t)=0$, the function $\operatorname{Log}G(t)$ is single-valued (which is true, no problem there) and thus Holder continuous.

So thats my question: How can we show that the function $\operatorname{Log}G(t)$ is H-continuous using the fact that $G(t)$ is H-continuous and $\operatorname{Ind}_cG(t)=0$?

Answer (score 2):

Since the curve $G(t)$ does not pass through $0$, the infimum of $\|G\|$ is strictly positive. Call it $m$. The logarithm (locally defined) is Lipschitz with constant $1/m$, as long as we stay outside of the disk $D(0,m)$. Applying a Lipschitz function to a Hölder continuous function preserves Hölder continuity.

Comment: Can you show analytically that the logarithm is indeed Lipschitz for $\left|z\right|>m$?

Comment: Yes, I can. Take the derivative.

Comment: Based on the mean value theorem?That the derivative is bounded?
I don't think that this is correct.Here $\operatorname{Log}$ is the complex logarithm.

Comment: Well, you are free to think what you want.